# PHP and jQuery realtime messaging system multiple problems

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to ajax and I'm trying to build a real-time (facebook like) messaging system with PHP and jQuery. Currently, when the user loads the page, messages are loaded from the database. Then, the script sends a get request every 2 seconds to get the latest messages from the database and displays them on the page. However, after a while, the connection times out and if I try to reload the website, the website does not load. It does load when I use a proxy. I feel it has something to do with the server blocking my ip.

Here is my current code (message refresh)

```
$(function() {
    var m = $('.messages');
    m.scrollTop(d.prop("scrollHeight"));
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("get_messages.php", function(result) {
            $('.messages').html(result);
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

How can I make this more efficient/better?

Comment: hmmm I don't like too much that you send requests to the server every 2 seconds. That will use A LOT of your server resources.

Comment: @Erick I know. I don't like it either. I feel that this is the reason I'm getting locked out of my own website. Can you suggest a better way?

Comment: In short: Stop using long-polling techniques for chat-like systems! It'll drain your server like a hammer! Try using websockets instead. This can be done with php, but other languages are more suitable for this. NodeJS for example. More info here: http://socket.io

Comment: @icecub Is this possibly the reason I can't access my website trough my ip but I can through a proxy?

Comment: Probebly not. There can be any number of reasons for that to happen. Most likely a loop in your polling causing problems to anyone connected for to long. It'll probebly happen to the proxy as well if you wait long enough.

Comment: @icecub OK, thanks for all your help. I'm gonna look into web sockets.

Comment: I happen to be working on a socket / php based chatsystem myself. It's far from finished and still bugged. But basic chatting works fine. I don't mind sharing it with you to get you on the road. But you'll have to click my name and contact me through email (on profile here) for that.

Comment: @icecub OK, I've emailed you

Comment: You should have a reply.

Comment: @icecub - websockets aren't any less draining, if the server isn't configured properly. Also, 2s is considered short-polling. Finally, for that kind of stuff, eventsource ( http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource + its polyfill for IE8) is by far the best, as long as the interaction is one-way.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel. Maybe use a project on github? https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat

Comment: Have you checked your browsers inspector?? You should see the type of response from the network request.. It might be returning a 500 error or similar for some reason.. In general this concept should work, But if its a public/shared server then most likely it is a server block. I do agree with sockets sort of.. But you might be limited by the server, Not your code.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the comments to your question are good, i would rather answer this in my own way..

First off, polling the server every 2 seconds.. In general should work, I would simply guess you are being blocked by the server.. Specially if it is a **public/shared server**.. As they have to restrict **traffic/high loads** so you dont weight it down for others.

First i would check your **browsers inspector/DOM**.. You might see that the network requests are coming back with an error code instead of a 200 status.. This should give you some indication.. Depending on on the server and how they respond.. Some return a 200 status/ok but still stop the script.

Another thing to consider is **cache**.. With your GET request, also post a timestamp with it.. This will force a new request every time.. jQuery can handle this in the background but certain browsers still fail in the area.. So post a **append a javascript timestamp to the URL** as well.

Otherwise also consider adding a subscript that **logs to a text file** and see if that stops logging as well, You might find some interesting results here.

And if all else fails, install/**test a local webserver** to your computer and test it that way.. This will also help you check if it is your server or your script.

If you try all of the above, You should find an answer to what is causing the issue or at least get some indications as to where or why it stops working.. The proxy simply to me suggests it is a server block, BUT also remember a proxy can change the way it requests your page.... So i would start with the browser inspector first.. This is my first point of reference when something does not work right.

**First/Main Question..** Is this a public/shared server or is it your own server that you have setup? If you have access to various **logs on the server**, check them as well..

Comment: It's a public server hosted on 000webhost.com. I doubt I have any access to logs. All of the request return a 200. I only have 100GB of bandwith currently so I doubt polling the server every 2 seconds is efficient. I don't think I can store messages on a database as I'm expecting thousands of users. It doesn't scale well unless I had my own server which I can't afford yet

Comment: Have you considered finding a pre-made host for this purpose, one that offers an API and allows you to use your own interface/rooms.. Sending a request every 2 seconds... sort of can work, as long as the URL / request data is very minimal.. eg.. a.php as the file.. and it simply returns a blank / page if no changes.. you also would use a cache / not modified header if no new messages which would make it use less data... In large scale, You would want a database and multiple servers.. But we all start small.. in time you will tune / adjust it as you get a feel for how it should work

Comment: http://www.programmableweb.com/news/57-chat-apis-skype-msn-messenger-and-google-talk/2012/03/07 Good list.. not sure how many would be of use.. But a starting point.. If you want to code it yourself.. You'll just need to impose limits until you control the serves / scale up

Comment: Would this allow multiple users to use the system at once? Can user A message user B while user C is messaging User D at the same time? And so on for lots of users

Comment: Depending on which provider, yes.. There would be a few free ones who have some limits.. as in say 200 users at once or 10 rooms. for example that is.. Otherwise perhaps try another web host. As some hosts are purely for static pages vs dynamic sites like yours

Comment: I am planning on buying a hosting plan. Which provider would you suggest for dynamic webpages?

Comment: Personally, i use to use lunarpages.com as have trusted them for years.. But a dedicated host would be ideal, as in a single PC/IP for your own site.. Not a shared.. Cheap paid hosting is still shared, they do both.. First install something like xampp on your PC and test your code to be sure.. I now host my own sites with my own hardware/connection..

Comment: Currently, without the plan, I'm considering creating a new text file for each users messaging session and then putting messages in that and also displaying messages from that, then deleting the text file as soon as the user is done messaging. Are there downsides to this?

Comment: If its a single room, it would work ok.. But as soon as they leave, the user / chat history would be gone as well.. I would almost try a single file for everyone for a room.. Each line is a message, or use a syntax to specify the user at the start of a line.. That way your not doing multiple reads/writes to multiple files. This would retain chat history, and you simple would append which is the quickest file right/update method.. Once the file reaches a large size, crop the top half and store the bottom half back into the file.. or something like that ?

Comment: What I meant was that it would basically be a Facebook like messaging system but with using txt files to store messages rather than a database. Would that work?